# npm install ignores own ssh+git repo

Tags: node.js, git, repository, package.json

In my company we use a Bitbucket server and I am developing a framework as npm module. I run `npm install git+ssh://git...`, npm will create a `node_modules/_PACKAGE_NAME_` folder with my sources.

When I add it to the `package.json` and run `npm install`, npm asks me for a fingerprint and then finishes installing all packages, but in `node_modules` there is no package of my git repo. That breaks my automation workflow, because I must separately install this repo by hand.

For information: I have to type my password when I run it manually.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a spelling mistake in the key, so npm could not create the folder